# How to invoke a method remotely?

Tags: java, web-services, rmi

I have two java projects. From project1 I have to call a method of project2. Both the projects are developed using the core java concepts and running seperately. As I know that in this case I will have to use any techniques that remotely invokes the methods(Am I correct?), like RMI, WebServices, JMS etc. I have to very frequently call the method of project2 from project1. What could be the best possible way to achieve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are your projects deployed to an application server or servlet container?

You can use web services to expose the method from Project 2. This would be standards based and would allow non-Java projects also in the future to access your service if required.

If it works for you, try to implement it in an asynchronous mode for better performance. Web services allow for asynchronous mode of invocation as well. However, for this, your Project 1 would also need expose a callback method.

EDIT:
I had come across that in Java 6, you can deploy web services outside of servlet container as well. Below link can help.

[Standalone web services in Java SE 6](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/tutorials/ws-eclipse-javase1/)

However not sure if this can be used in production environments.

Comment: My projects are not deployed in any container/server, they are running on jvm. If i make project2 a web service then i will have to deploy it in the web container?

Answer (score 0):

RMI is used in Client-Server architecture. There will be a server program that will implement your interface extending Remote and it will have definitions or calls to other methods at server and it will bind an object. Then you will need a client program that will look up for that object and using that object, it will call methods on Server.

So if your projects are running as Client-Server then you can try this thing.

Next thing you are talking about is WebServices. WebServices provide access to some code written at server to its clients over a network via specific protocols. In this your code will be running on a server and you will access it from your client using Web Service.

Now it is up to you what kind of architecture you are following for your projects and which method is more useful and suitable for your scenerio.